# Topology on CW complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to understand the following statement in the book *Algebraic Topology* by Hatcher.
Here, $X$ is a CW complex.

A subset $A\subset X$ is open in $X$ iff $\Phi^{-1} (A)$ is open in $B^n$ where $\Phi$ is a characteristic map for each $n$-cell $e^n$

Forward direction seems obvious as mentioned in the text.
For the backward direction, the book says we can use **induction on n**. So I tried this for $n=0,1$ but struggling to show this in general.

Maybe I need to show that the map is a quotient map?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a CW complex $X$ is given the *weak topology* with respect to its skeleta $(X^n\subseteq X)_{n\geq 0}$. This means that a subset $A\subseteq X$ is open if and only if $A^n:=A\cap X^n$ is open in $X^n$ for each $n\geq 0$. This is part $(3)$ of Hatcher's definition.

Also recall that the $n$-skeleton $X^n$ is a quotient of the disjoint union $X^{n-1}\bigsqcup_\alpha D^n_\alpha$, where $\alpha$ indexes the $n$-cells of $X$. It follows that a subset $A^n\subseteq X^n$ is open if and only if $A^n\cap X^{n-1}$ is open in $X^{n-1}$ and $\Phi_\alpha^{-1}(A)\subseteq D^n_\alpha$ is open for each $\alpha$. This is part $(2)$ of Hatcher's definition. We conclude that for a fixed $n$, a subset $A\subset X$ is open in $X^n$ if and only if $\Phi^{-1}(A)$ is open in $D^k$ for each $k$-cell $\Phi$ of $X$ and each $k\leq n$.

Now, returning to the first paragraph we have that a subset $A\subset X$ is open if and only if $A\cap X^n$ is open in $X^n$ for each $n\geq 0$, if and only if $\Phi^{-1}(A)$ is open in $D^k$ for each $k$-cell $\Phi$, each $k\leq n$ and each $n\geq 0$, if and only if $\Phi^{-1}(A)$ is open in $D^k$ for each $k$-cell $\Phi$ and each $k\geq 0$.

Comment: So to use induction on n, I would assume $A\cap X^{n-1}$ is open in $X^{n-1}$. Then since $\Phi^{-1}(A) $is open in $B^n$ and $X^n=X^{n-1} \sqcup (\bigsqcup_{\alpha} B_\alpha^n)$/~, $A\cap X^n$ is open in $X^n$ hence holds for all $n$, am I right? Btw thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Hjhj yes, that's the idea.